# New Grails Install Way Slow

Tags: grails

I'm just starting to learn Grails and Groovy.  Did a fresh install of Grails 1.3.8 today and it crawls - I must have something in my environment causing a problem.  I ran create-app (following a tutorial), then run-app.  Both took quite a while but hey, first time thru.  Ran run-app again, took almost 5 minutes, apparently int eh compiling phase.  Windows 7 machine with 4 GB memory, Intel i5 CPU.  Don't know where to start looking, but know this isn't normal.

Comment: my pc has a 2.7ghz processor, 4 gbs of ram (2.98 usable), and windows 7 (32-bit), grails does fine. maybe your virus scanner is going nuts, look in the task manager and see what's going on.

Comment: Nothing much.  Memory and CPU usage both go up a little, but far from maxed out.

Answer (score 1):

When I've run into this normally I'm out of heap or permGen space.  Fire up visualvm and check both of those memory limits.   It'll slowdown considerably before crashing if your memory limits are too small

Comment: Never used Visualvm - I'm just starting to get into this stuff.  And I can't imagine that I have memory problems with an empty shell of an application?

Comment: Most memory defaults are for Java applications.  Groovy uses more permgen space than Straight Java (each closure is a class, etc.)

Comment: IMO, Java memory management isn't the best out of the box experience.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how it happens for you. I have 2gb ram and I run Ubuntu on pc and it's so fast. First check your memory limits.

And for your question, you can find a good disscussion over [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-development-is-really-slow-tc4257651.html).

Comment: Yeah, runs real fast on my old XP box with just 2GB.  My 4GB Win7 machine is almost unusably slow.  And I'm talking about just running create-app then run-app without adding any functionality, so I doubt that it's my memory.  I'm really stumped at this point.